# Javascript calling so fast

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an annoying little issue here.  I have code which loads content from page2 and appends it to `#content`. That works, but sometimes it happens twice, then appends page3 before page2.  Thats because in page3, there is just one post, but in page2, 4 posts.

How can I make my code wait until the append finishes to run again? Here's my code:

```
$(window).scroll(
  function(){
    if(browserName != "safari") {
      var curScrollPos = $('html').scrollTop();
    }
    else {
      var curScrollPos = $('body').scrollTop();
    }

    if(curScrollPos > 218) {
      $("#sidebar").addClass("open");
    }

    if(curScrollPos < 218) {
      $("#sidebar").removeClass("open");
    }

    var scrollBottom = $(document).height() - $(window).height() - $(window).scrollTop();

    if(scrollBottom == 0) {
      if(home != 0 || search != 0 || category != 0) { 
        if(currentPage < numPages) {
          $("#main .loader-posts").fadeIn();
          currentPage++;

          if(search == 1) {
            var getPostsUrl = "page/"+currentPage+"/?s="+searchTerm;
          }
          else {
            var getPostsUrl = "page/"+currentPage;
          }

          $.get(getPostsUrl, function(data) {
                  $("#main .loader-posts").fadeOut(
                    'slow',
                    function(){
                      var newPosts = $(data).find("#content").html();
                      $("#content").append(newPosts);
                      $('#container.tiles').masonry('reload');
                    });
                });
        }
      }
      else {

      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable that keeps track of whether you are loading the next page or not and then only load if you are not currently loading something else.  This is the root of your problem.  `.scroll()` may fire twice before the next section is loaded, and as long as `currentPage < numPages` it will increment `currentPage` and load again.  And, because `.get()` is asynchronous, you are not guaranteed to finish the first `.get()` request before any subsequent request.  Adding a `loading` state fixes this.

```
var loading = 0;  // Loading state

if (scrollBottom == 0) {

    if (home != 0 || search != 0 || category != 0) {

        if (currentPage < numPages && !loading) {  // Only proceed if not loading
            loading = 1; // We have initiated loading

            $("#main .loader-posts").fadeIn();
            currentPage++;

            if (search == 1) {
                var getPostsUrl = "page/" + currentPage + "/?s=" + searchTerm;
            } else {
                var getPostsUrl = "page/" + currentPage;
            }

            $.get(getPostsUrl, function(data) {
                $("#main .loader-posts").fadeOut('slow', function() {
                    var newPosts = $(data).find("#content").html();
                    $("#content").append(newPosts);
                    $('#container.tiles').masonry('reload');
                    loading = 0;  // We are done loading
                });
            });
        }
    } else {

    }

}
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked pretty well! I did something similar, but didnt work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add an isBusy flag that you can check before the $.get(), and set it to false in the $.get() callback?